# how to map elements dynamically using Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

The problem is the following:

I have a list of items in the page with the same identifier except a number, and I map them individually, for instance:

```
@FindBy(id = "element(1)")
public WebElement field1
@FindBy(id = "element(2)")
public WebElement field2
@FindBy(id = "element(3)")
public WebElement field3
@FindBy(id = "element(4)")
public WebElement field4
```

Then I write methods to fetch the values for each one of the elements

```
public void getElement1Text(){field1.Text..}
...
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is something like this:

```
@FindBy(id = "element(VARIABLE)")
public WebElement field
```

Then loop for the amount of fields, example:

```
public void getElementText(){
   for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){field[i].Text...}
}
```

I know how to do this in Ruby, not in Java, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a list of similar elements

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'(element(')]")
public List<WebElement> fields;


Then read the each values in the similar elements one by one

public void getElementText(){
      for (WebElement objElement : fields) {
        System.out.println(objElement.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're describing a method like this:

```
public List getElementText(WebDriver driver){
    List elementTextList = new ArrayList();
    //this loops 1-3
    for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        //add each text by finding the element, notice elemenIdGoesHere should be changed
        elementTextList.add(driver.findElement(By.id("elementIdGoesHere" + i)).getText());
    }
    //return the list of texts
    return elementTextList;
}
```

Comment: Nice!! This works for me, just like the solution above... thanks guys!!